# Timeline make items always resizable

Tags: javascript, css, vis.js

I have a vis.js Timeline and I want to be able to always resize items, even when they are not selected.

So, is there a way to always make items resizable without having to select them first? Like the "itemsAlwaysDraggable" setting?

I cannot seem to find it in the docs or examples.